# Enable windows logon prompt in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication

I have a asp.net application which uses windows authentication. The user are able to access the site without problem as it a intranet application within the organization. But now i need the user to prompt window logon after filling in the details it should authenticate in IIS. How can i achieve this.

Comment: So...to confirm. Currently the users are automagically logging on with their windows credentials (via integrated security). However you want to make it so that the user must explicitly MANUALLY log on?

Comment: ya exactly i need them to forcefully authenticate in IIS

Comment: You want to switch from `windows authentication` to `basic authentication` or `digest authentication`. However these schemes aren't as secure as `windows auth`. You may want to run these over https to be sure.

Comment: You _are_ authenticating in IIS. You don't see the prompt because the user has already authenticated. Try accessing the page from a machine that is not logged into the domain, and you'll see the prompt.

Comment: @JohnSaunders hence my comment for clarification. It sounds like the OP for some business reason requires manual auth step.